# GitHub API: Get a PR of a private repo for collaborators

Tags: node.js, github, github-api

I would like to get a single pull request of a private repo using [this GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request).

But I can only do so when the authenticated user is the owner of the repo. When the user is a collaborator, the API server returns an error:

```
[Error: {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}]
```

Is there a way to get a single PR of a private repo via API when the user is a collaborator?

**Additional info**

Using node-github-api, this is what I have implemented:

```
var github = new GitHub({ version: '3.0.0' });

github.authenticate({
  type: 'oauth',
  token: // user's token
});

github.pullRequests.get({
  headers: { 'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.VERSION.diff' },
  user:  //owner's name,
  repo: //repo name,
  number: // pr number
}, ...);
```

Comment: What scopes does the token have? Is it a personal access token or a token associated with an OAuth app?